# XCode Objective C warnings/ how to permanently delete properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created some variables in XYZ.h using properties, then synthesized them in XYZ.m.

However, after I deleted the properties from both XYZ.h and XYZ.m, Xcode thought the properties still existed, and threw up warnings in my implementation file about all of the properties I deleted, saying they required a method implementation.

Looking into this further, I found that the properties were still listed for the class in the symbol navigator despite not existing anywhere in the code. Further, when I "jump" to where these variables are supposedly declared, it jumps to the very top of XYZ.h where it is obvious that nothing of the sort is there.

Other than trashing XYZ.h and XYZ.m and repasting the code in, how can I remove these properties permanently and/or what is the correct method of removing them (I'm guessing there's something else I have to do other than purging them from the code)?

I've tried already running clean and clean build folder, as well as temporarily recreating the variables and destroying them, but nothing has worked thus far.

I can provide any additional information needed.

Edit: Very bizarre, once I restarted the computer, it loaded up the XYZ.h file with all of the properties still there. Apparently all of the saves I made to the header file were not being saved for reasons unknown despite all appearances to the contrary. Everything's fine now, I deleted the properties, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Does this happen to every single property you declare and subsequently delete?

Comment: Presumably this is Xcode 4 or later.  It does this.  I forget the details, but there's a way to force a rebuild of the symbol table it keeps on the side.  Simple clean and build won't do it, and even deleting the file might not.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange.
Are the properties IBOutlets? If so, remove them from the xib.
If not, you might try deleting Xcode's derived data:
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

good luck

Comment: I agree with this.  Xcode gets mad if you delete IBOutlet properties but leave them active in your Xib/Storyboard.  Also, have you tried closing/reopening Xcode?